# DB separation with master data and its copy data for every year

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My question is very realistic and may match with someone's requirement.

My application is built using Java8, Spring Boot, MySQL. It is working fine.

In application we have database tables like in below format

**master tables -** These tables contains the users, forms, etc.

**child tables -** These tables are created from the above master tables(just create the copy of master records in child tables for new year so that user can fill the data against them), here we some tables are not copied for child like users. As users will be same for each year but other data like forms will be copied which can be different and edited if required for that particular year.

Year by Year this child tables get increasing in size. So I thought to separate the yearwise data.
It means there will be one master db. and then separate child dbs for each year. There is no relationship between two years data but yeah there is relationship between master and and every year. So here cross database foreign key also need to be think.

**Why this requirement** - We can take the separate db backup year wise with combination of master db. Let suppose if I there is any issue in one year data then I took back up of master + only that specific year data where issue happened and worked on the issue.

I'm not getting the complete idea how we can do this. If anyone can help me here it will be really appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: See about partitioning. It may be suited to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you said

> There is no relationship between two years data but yeah there is
> relationship between master and and every year. So here cross database
> foreign key also need to be think.

The solution is

- backup database to safe place (master and detail data).
- truncate data (master and detail data).
- write new data (master and detail data) to DBMS (database management system).